# Execute SQL queries stored in a object variable

Tags: sql, ssis

I am struggling with the following scenario, please help.

- Got a request to create 20 different data extracts(using different sql queries) from sql database to a text file and SFTP using cozyroc ext that we use inside ssis.
- Instead of creating 20 different connections and creating multiple variables to hold outfile variables etc, I thought of using for each loop container in SSIS.

My approach:

- I created a table and loaded all 20 queries, each row is a query with following columns `id, sqlstatement, metric`.
- I created an "Execute SQL Task" - for SQL statement I used (select distinct metric from table) and result set for this would be full result set. Assigned this to variable MetricObject object variable, hence stored all 20 different metrics in the object variable.
- Now I created the foreach loop container - inside the collection tab I called MetricObject variable in the ADO object source variable and selected rows in the first table hence can be iterated for each metric, hence iterates 20 times. And assigned this to a Metric variable.
- Now inside the foreach loop container I created an Execute SQL Task that holds the stored procedure that calls the table created in the first step and pass the metric variable in step c and generate the queries that are stored in step a and in turn hold the SQL statement om the new created variable called `sqlstatement`. My expectation is `sqlstatement` variable will hold the SQL from the first step.
- Finally I called the variable in the data flow task and map it to text file and generate the text file.
- This can be looped several times until it reaches the end of metric values and load all text file in one go.

For some reason I am not successful. Can you let me know if this is the right approach? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have done something similar where I created my own job queue and all the SQL query are stored in a DB table.  The way I handle it is somewhat similar.  I loop through all the query and put them into a variable.  The difference is (since I dont know what the headers or how many columns will be) I execute the SQL into an object, then use C# script task to take the object, convert it to a dataset, then dynamically save the dataset (and headers/columns) to a .csv file using the C# code.  I get the file name/path to export this to from the same database table where the query is stored.